# Critical path with given start and end times instead of cost

Tags: algorithm, project-management

I'm having trouble computing the critical path of a network of activities. The data I have to work with is a little different than what I have seen in simple examples on the web. That is I have the start and end times of each activities, from whom I deduce the length. I have been using that algorithm to compute earliest and latest start and end times for each activity :

"To find the earliest start times, start at activities with no predecessors, and say they start at time zero. Then repeatedly find an activity whose predecessors' start times have all been filled, and set the start time to the maximum predecessor finish time.

To find the latest start times, run the preceding algorithm backwards. Start at activities with no successors. Set their finish time to the maximum finish time from the previous phase. Repeatedly find a predecessor whose successors have all been evaluated. Set its finish time to the earliest successor's start time.

Now it is trivial to evaluate slack = latest start – earliest start. Some chain of events will have slack time equal to zero; this is the critical path."

source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368404/find-the-critical-path-and-slack-time

My code is identifying sometimes correctly the critical activities which compose the critical path, but due to the data I have, it sometimes fail. I have found when it does happen : it's when the given times for an activity (from whom cost is deduced) does not respect the early and latest times computed. Right now I only take into account the cost of each activity, but obviously it is not enough because in case like the one in picture below, critical path computed is not accurate : 
[one fail case for algorithm above http://imageshack.us/a/img688/2420/casemp.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img688/2420/casemp.png)

Obviously activity B is critical (if its end time is shifted, the end of project is also shifted) but the algorithm compute a slack of 1...

I don't know how to change the algorithm to make it work for case above.

Answer (score 0):

I found some easy way to identify the critical activities from the data I have. For each activity, I simulate one second delay (add one second to the end time) and propagate that delay to all successors and test if it affects the time of last activity. If so, that task is critical.

This way works great, I have now a list of all the critical activities, but for some case it can take several seconds (23 seconds for 450 activities with a lot of dependances !). So still trying to find a better way.